# Nginx pass all requests to specific S3 file

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket with the static contents of my site and I have an EC2 instance that receives all of the traffic to the site.

I want to have every request to the EC2 return a specific file from my S3, but I want to keep the URL the same as the user inserted it.

**Example**: Let's assume that my file is located in /path/index.html
If the user makes a request to www.mydomain.com, I want to serve that file, and if the user makes a request to www.mydomain.com/some/random/path/ I still want to serve the same file. The last requirement is that the location will stay the same. That is, the user will still see www.mydoamin.com and www.mydoamin.com/some/random/path/ in the browser, even though the same file was served.

Here's the nginx config file I have so far, which doesn't seem to work:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    ssl off;

    location / {
            proxy_http_version     1.1;
            proxy_set_header       Host 'some-host.s3.amazonaws.com';
            proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
            proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
            proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
            proxy_buffering        off;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;


            resolver               8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
            resolver_timeout       10s;

            proxy_pass             http://some-host.s3.amazonaws.com/front-end/index.html;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to use proxy to keep your domain. It looks like you already have that. To apply the same rules to any path they choose, I think you can just use url rewriting (not to be confused with redirect). More simply though, I think you can just pattern match the location like location /* and then proxy the url will stay whatever the user enters

Comment: you can try caching if here is only static files: https://gist.github.com/mikhailov/9639593

Comment: @mikhailov Thanks! It's an AngularJS site. So the site is composed of static files but is updated continuously. Most of the site's files are version-ed and cached, but I don't cache the index.html file because I want the user to always get the latest version of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up using a variable. This solved the problem:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    ssl off;

    location / {
            proxy_http_version     1.1;
            proxy_set_header       Host 'some-host.s3.amazonaws.com';
            proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
            proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
            proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
            proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
            proxy_buffering        off;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;

            resolver               172.16.0.23 valid=300s;
            set $indexfile         "some-host.s3.amazonaws.com/front-end/index.html";
            proxy_pass             http://$indexfile;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works great, but I still have a question, why we can't specify a full URL in a **proxypass** directive, like:
`proxy_pass             "some-host.s3.amazonaws.com/front-end/index.html";`  
but using variable instead?

Comment: @ArtemDolobanko according to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass when variables are used in `proxy_pass`, then "the part of a request URI to be replaced cannot be determined." In that case, Nginx passes the URI as it is in the directive. I'm not sure what's the underlying reason it cannot determine which part to replace though.