# Nginx Proxy Pass S3 specific html file

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

I there, before I had my files on my localhost and I was able to serve them just fine. Now, I moved my static files to S3, but I want to serve the  index.html starter file with a custom domain. From the index.html must be possible to navigate to other `.html`.

So far I got:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    charset   utf-8;

    server_name mydomain;

    location / {


 proxy_set_header       Host 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com';
        proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
        proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        set $indexfile         "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myprod-bucket/static/js/frontend/build_v0.5/";
        proxy_pass             https://$indexfile;

        # expires 1y;
        log_not_found off;

        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd_finder;
    }

}
```

I can't seem to find any examples that work for my case, what am I doing wrong??

**UPDATE:** I changed this a bit based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/22843758/977622 and I started getting:

`Refused to execute the script from '../vendor.5ad3d736.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

and

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "../styles/main.b812e04a.css".`

Comment: whats in your /etc/nginx/mime.types config? Also you can set a default mime type in your location block.

Answer (score 0):

In a proxy scenario content type is specified by the origin server (S3 in this case), unless overridden. You can specify mime types on S3 objects when you upload them. If you do it through S3 web interface, make sure you do not uncheck '*Figure out content types automatically*'. AWS cli tools also guess mime types automatically, unless specified otherwise. If you use something else to upload the files, you need to consul the corresponding tool's manual/API reference.

Also you could serve you website directly from S3, see [Hosting a Static Website on Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)

Comment: i checked and the METADATA of the files on S3 is correct the .js (application/javascript) and the .css (text/css).
Could my nginx configuration be wrong? do you see anything wrong?
Hosting it directly from S3 is not an option because i don't have control of the DNS to point it there.

Comment: What's the content type (and other headers) you receive if you access that js file directly on S3?

Comment: On Chrome i am getting `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/css..`

Comment: Yeah, but what are the *headers* when you put that https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myprod-bucket/static/js/frontend/build_v0.5/index.html into the browser address bar?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's still relevant for you, but I'd suggest you serve your CSS and other static files directly from S3 and not via your Nginx. That is, serve your `index.html` with a `proxy_pass` as you do now, but the links to the CSS and JS files inside your `index.html` should be absolute, with your S3 bucket as the domain.

This will both solve your problem here, and would be better for other reasons such as:

- You'll reduce CPU and network costs from the server running the Nginx.
- You'll serve your site faster by not going through your own server for every static file request.
- S3 offers encryption, compression, ability to add a CDN and many other useful features. Unless there's a compelling reason to go through your own server, I'd avoid it.

Note that your users will still view your site via your own domain, it's only the CSS and JS files that will be served from the S3 domain.

Comment: Serving files directly from S3 isn't necessarily faster, it depends on RTT and TCP Congestion Window. In practice serving large amount of static files doesn't require more than 5% CPU on medium type of EC2 instance, static content is also cacheable. Having EC2 and S3 bucket in the same location is recommended because inter-region traffic costs nothing opposite to serving data from S3 directly where every single request is being paid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your files (objects) in S3 don't have the correct `Content-Type`. S3 automatically adds all Metadata as headers to the response for each object.

You can fix that by re-uploading them or modifying the Metadata for each of them. Not sure what method you are using, but the `Key` is `Content-Type` and the `Value` should be `text/css`, 'application/javascript` or whatever is relevant:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata

Example screenshot from the AWS Web Console:
[image]